# How to update a field of Django Model Object whenever that particular object is fetched as a part of QuerySet from Database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I have a field called **pending_since** for a **Ticket** model. This contains the the difference between the date when the ticket is created ( **created_on** field ) and the current date.

Now, when a single ticket is fetched, then I am able to update this field as below.

**views.py**

```
    def pending_days_calculator(date1):
       current_date = timezone.now()
       diff = current_date - date1
       diff_in_days = diff.total_seconds() / ( 60*60*24)
       pending_days = round(diff_in_days,2)
       return pending_days

    @login_required(login_url=settings.CUSTOM_LOGIN_URL)
    def ticket_detail(request, ticket_no):
       ticket = Ticket.objects.get(ticket_no=ticket_no)
       ticket.pending_since = pending_days_calculator(ticket.created_on)
       ticket.save()
       if request.method == 'POST':
           .....other logic here.....
```

But, when a bunch of **Ticket** objects are fetched at a time as shown below, is there any way to update this field for each object, other than looping through the queryset.

```
    @login_required(login_url=settings.CUSTOM_LOGIN_URL)
    def common_pool(request):
        tickets = request.user.ticket_set.exclude(ticket_status='closed').order_by('sla')
```

**Ticket** model has ForeignKey reference to user model **GHDUser**

**models.py** for reference

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    ticket_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    raised_by_user = models.ForeignKey(GHDUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='raised_ticket', default=1)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    pending_since = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

Comment: Do you really need this to be a model field? You could instead use a property that calculates this difference dynamically.

Comment: @dgw , it didn't occur to me earlier. But using a property solved the problem. Thanks a lot. 

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate `pending_since` for each object of Django Model, you can use a property method for it

```
@property
def pending_since(self):
    return pending_days_calculator(self.created_on)
```

This would do the job. You can also move the logic in `pending_days_calculator` in side the property.